# Look for a filename in a directory compare from a row in a sqlite database and copy contents

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, compare, filenames

I'm really green and new in the python world, and I'm learning as I go.
I'm trying to extract a series of rows from a sqlite database.  (which I've done).
I then write those to a csv file.

I'm  now trying to compare a row from that database and look into a directory where there is a filename with the same value.
So if row cell data is 1000 the file would be 1000.txt amongst a long list of others in a directory.  They're all in the same folder.

Once I find the file.  I want to then read that files contents and then add that to another row in my csv that I've created.

So my main question is how to compare to the directory based on the cell data which is the filename (no extension is provided in the cell just a number reference).

```
# Open file, get lines, close file.
# Probably prudent to add try-except here for bad file names.
msgfile = {}
filename = {}
for row in c:
    msgfile = msgID[row[1]]
    for filenames in os.walk(r"D:\my_source_directory\"):
 ##stuck here 
                             f_open = open(msgfile,'r')
                             lines = f_open.readlines()
                             f_open.close()
                             print ()
```

Comment: You can't have the \ character as the last character in a string, even a raw string literal, unless you escape it. In this case, however, you just plain don't need it.

Comment: noted and changed thanks

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` yields tuples that contain `(current_dir, childrendirs, files)` so at the very least, your loop needs to look like `for _, _, files in os.walk(...):` that may be the root of your problems, but there's not much to go on here.

Comment: I'm thinking after a little more research that maybe os.walk isnt what I need here.  Since I already have the value I need loaded.  It was pulled from a column in a sql database.  I just need to say look at row1 and find that matching name in directory and open that file (its a text) and read contents.  Then I'll append it to the new file I'm making.. I'm just stuck on how to get it to compare what I have and the file that I need